# Bilevel optimization with multiple features

Tags: machine-learning, model

For my data, I have varying levels of a categorical variable, and for each level, I have a dataset of numerical values and positions of sensors for those values.

Specifically, I have multiple objects differing by a simple design factor. Each one of these objects has a dataset of temperature values at scattered positions. (each column represents a sensor, each row represents one second).

I need to build a model that can essentially understand the relationship between the temperatures, time, and positions (because of heat flow) - **essentially the temperature distribution.** I also need to compare these with the categorical data (object design) so that I can understand the relationship between the design factor and the temperature distribution / heat flow.

I'm new to machine learning but I've done some research on here and elsewhere about what to use and haven't been able to come up with much except for bilevel optimization for the "nested" variables that I have. I'm still confused on what to do. What kind of model should I use?

Comment: Just want to confirm if the levels in your variables truly categorical or are they ordered?

Comment: They are truly categorical - different internal structure patterns. There's no way to quantify it.